# Create a filename with correct extension with Mime type

Tags: php, mime-types

I have the content of a file and the mime type stored. I do not have the original filename or the original extension. I need to create a filename with the correct extension for the file based off of the stored mime type information. Any what to do this?

Answer (score 2):

You can create an association with MIME type and extension like:

```
$ext = array(

 'image/jpeg' => 'jpg'
  //> Etc
);
```

Then you can write your file with:

```
file_put_contents('file.'.$ext[$fileType],$fileContents);
```

You can get a list of ext/mime here:

http://www.webmaster-toolkit.com/mime-types.shtml

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" extension for a mime type.

For instance image/jpeg can have .jpg or .jpeg. Or on many systems any extension you like (or none) as it contains a valid JFIF header.

For instance audio/ogg could be a .ogg or .oga or .spx.